# Formatting list of acronyms

Tags: acro

I am using the acro package to define and reference acronyms in a document. This has been working fine and the list prints. However, everything in the list is double spaced and I would like to have acronyms with very long long-names be only single spaced. A sample of code I am working with is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper,verbose,tmargin=1.25in,bmargin=1.25in,lmargin=1.4in,rmargin=1.15in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-18pt}{\baselineskip}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\centering\normalsize}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}

\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{list-style=tabular, only-used=false, sort=false}
\DeclareInstance{acro-title}{empty}{sectioning}{name-format =}

\DeclareAcronym{VLA}{
    short = VLA,
    long  = This acronym is so long that the long from requires two lines to display it
}

\DeclareAcronym{EVIL}{
    short = EVIL,
    long  = Every Villain is Lemons
}

\begin{document}
\doublespacing

\chapter*{NOMENCLATURE}

\pagestyle{plain}
\printacronyms[heading = empty]

\pagebreak{}

\end{document}
```

And the output looks like this

[image: Acronym that requires two lines]

I would like the VLA acronym to be single spaced, but have double spacing between the VLA and EVIL acronyms.

Best!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Please give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. Cutting your code down to a MWE may well reveal what your problem actually is. In any case, it is really difficult to help you without more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding

```
\DeclareAcroListStyle{tabular}{table}{
  table = tabular ,
  before = \singlespacing\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.655}
}
```

to your MWE gives

[image]

`\singlespacing` also adds an additional vertical skip of `\baselineskip` which you might want to remove:

```
\DeclareAcroListStyle{tabular}{table}{
  table = tabular ,
  before = \singlespacing\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.655}
}
```

`1.655` is the stretch value `setspace` uses for double spacing when the font size is 12pt.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you so much. The only question I have is how did you decide that 1.655 was the 'correct' value of the array stretch?

Comment: I looked it up in `setspace.sty`. It's what the package uses for double spacing for 12pt.

Answer (score 0):

One crude solution is to remove the `\doublespacing` command and add a `\newline` to every long definition as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
  \usepackage[letterpaper,verbose,tmargin=1.25in,bmargin=1.25in,lmargin=1.4in,rmargin=1.15in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-18pt}{\baselineskip}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\centering\normalsize}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}

\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{list-style=tabular, only-used=false, sort=false}
\DeclareInstance{acro-title}{empty}{sectioning}{name-format =}

\DeclareAcronym{VLA}{
    short = VLA,
    long  = This acronym is so long that the long from requires two lines to display it\newline
}

\DeclareAcronym{EVIL}{
    short = EVIL,
    long  = Every Villain is Lemons\newline
}


\begin{document}

\chapter*{NOMENCLATURE}

\pagestyle{plain}

\printacronyms[heading = empty]

\pagebreak{}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]